# Subquery SQL for link name and firstname

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hello I would like to retrieve the name and the first name in the user table thanks to the id contained in the message table (id_receive and id_send) in sql via a subquery

````
SELECT user.nom FROM user
    WHERE user.id IN (
        SELECT message.id_send, message.id_receive FROM message WHERE message.id=1
    ) 
    ```
````

Comment: `user.id IN` expects one column, a user id. But your subquery returns two columns, and none of them is a user id.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using `EXISTS`, twice:

```
SELECT u.nom
FROM user u
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM message m WHERE m.id = 1 AND u.id = id_send) OR
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM message m WHERE m.id = 1 AND u.id = id_receive) ;
```

However, a `JOIN` might also be appropriate:

```
SELECT u.nom
FROM user u JOIN
     message m
     ON u.id IN (m.id_send, id_receive)
WHERE m.id = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it isn't actually what you want but it looks like this is what you're trying to do:

```
SELECT user.nom FROM user
    WHERE user.id IN (
        SELECT message.id_send FROM message WHERE message.id=1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT message.id_receive FROM message WHERE message.id=1
    )
```

The query that drives the IN should return a single column of values

Try and conceive that in works like this:

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE c IN(
  1 
  2
  3
)
```

Not like this:

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE c IN(
  1     2     3  
)
```

Nor like this:

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE c IN(
  1     2     3
  4     5     6
  
)
```

It might help you reember that the query inside it must return a single column, but multiple rows, all of qhich are searched for a matching value `c` by IN

Comment: Thank you very much that's exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Small addition to your original query to make it working:

```
SELECT user.nom FROM user
    WHERE user.id IN (
        SELECT unnest(array[message.id_send, message.id_receive])
        FROM message
        WHERE message.id=1
    )
```